# Questions duplicated in featured question list

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bounty

Notice one question shows up three times and another question shows up twice.

[image]

Comment: That's weird. What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: ...and now it works again.

Comment: Same as I. Gotta hate those Schrodinger's bugs... :P

Comment: If anyone can figure out how to make this happen...

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a rare caching issue?

We've since upgraded our caching servers substantially. If you see this again let us know.